# Integration Test for Homemade Genetic Programming Framework

Tags: c#, integration-testing, genetic-algorithm, genetic-programming

I’ve written my own Genetic Programming Framework. I’ve got a really good level of unit test coverage, so I’m confident that the individual components work correctly.

What I’m looking for is a reasonably simple problem that is well suited to genetic programming that I can use as an integration level test, that will check my framework works and can find solutions.

I can’t use the original problem I wrote the framework to solve as an integration test because:

1. I don’t know if the problem is solvable with a genetic programming
   approach.
2. Each generation will take around 5 minutes to run.

Can anyone please describe a simple, non-trivial problem, that is well suited to genetic programming?
Thanks.

Comment: What about solving Rubik's cube by genetic programming? [Rubik's Cube GA Solver](https://github.com/TodorBalabanov/RubiksCubeGeneticAlgorithmsSolver)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Genetic Programming can be applied to regression and classification problems. Symbolic regression maybe is the simplest one. You have some training data and you have to discover a mathematical formula (computer program) which approximates the given data.

For instance, you have the following data (input, output) generated by a function f(x):

0   1

1   5

2   31

3   121

4   341

5   781

6   1555

7   2801

8   4681

9   7381

find a function which links the input to output.
Answer: the function is f(x) = x^4 + x^3 + x^2 + x + 1

This definitively should not take 5 minutes per generation ... it fact it should take less than 1 second per generation when you have a population of 50 individuals.

Edit: I just test the problem with my GP implementation (from http://mepx.org) and it runs in less than 0.02 seconds for an entire run (50 individuals for 50 generations and the code length is 50).